# What does it mean when "rake gems" returns gems with no state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Here is the command line output:

```
breefiel@breefield.com [~/rails_apps/recurse]# rake gems
(in /home/breefiel/rails_apps/recurse)
 - [ ] authlogic 
 - [ ] acts_as_archive 
 - [ ] haml 

I = Installed
F = Frozen
R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
```

Notice that the gems are not I, F, or R...what does this mean?
This is just one indicator that my gems aren't being detected. When I install them, they are stored in "/home/breefiel/ruby/gems", and I've added the line

```
Gem.path.push "/home/breefiel/ruby/gems"
```

To my environment.rb.
However, "rake gems" is still returning the above output, so I'm not sure. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The code is determined with this line of code:

```
code = gem.loaded? ? (gem.frozen? ? (gem.framework_gem? ? "R" : "F") : "I") : " "
```

The blank code means the gem wasn't loaded. Make sure `config.gem '...'` doesn't have `:lib => false` because that will stop them from being loaded with Rails.

If that isn't the case, looking in `Rails::GemDependency`, `loaded?` will be set by `load` or determined by looking for the files (if `load` isn't called).

I have two suggestions,

1. Move your gems into the normal directories and see if that fixes the problem; or
2. Manually call `load` using a ruby console and see if you get any errors that rails is missing.

Comment: I'll try moving them into the /vendor/gems
I can't run ./script/consol because it complains about gems not existing :/

But that code, combined with the other comments is very helpful. Thanks!